# Is there a way to use Union with Use?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, union

I have several USE statements that I wish to UNION to get all the results in one result set but I cannot do this since UNION can only be used with SELECT. Is there a work around or any way to achieve my goal another way?

Example:

```
USE Customer 
select min(len(Password)) as min, 
    max(len(Password)) as max, 
    avg(len(Password)) as avg 
FROM Password
USE website 
select min(len(password)) as min, 
    max(len(password)) as max, 
    avg(len(password)) as avg 
FROM Password
```

I have many more of these statements using different databases & tables so wanted to group them all together.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are all these schemas on the same server? If so, you can just use as `customer.Password` and `website.Password`. If they exist on different servers, you can use linked servers and then use a similar syntax `linkedserver.schema.table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `USE` statement. Use fully qualified names for your objects (tables, views etc)

```
SELECT
    min(len(Password)) AS minPassword, 
    max(len(Password)) AS maxPassword, 
    avg(len(Password)) AS avgPasswword 
FROM 
    Customer.dbo.Password
UNION
select 
    min(len(password)), 
    max(len(password)), 
    avg(len(password))
FROM 
    Website.dbo.Password
```

this assumes your tables are have dbo as owner.

Comment: Think you were the first to post this answer so accepted your answer. It works, thanks.

Comment: @Alias, +1 Yes he was the first by only one second.

Answer (score 1):

You can qualify table names using the `[database name].[schema name].[table name]` within the `UNION` like so:

```
select min(len(Password)) as min, 
    max(len(Password)) as max, 
    avg(len(Password)) as avg 
FROM customer.schemaname.Password
UNION ALL 
select min(len(password)) as min, 
    max(len(password)) as max, 
    avg(len(password)) as avg 
FROM website.schemaname.Password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preface your table name with the database to use and then you can use a `UNION ALL` to query them at the same time:

```
select min(len(Password)) as min, 
    max(len(Password)) as max, 
    avg(len(Password)) as avg 
FROM Customer.yourSchema.Password
UNION ALL
select min(len(password)) as min, 
    max(len(password)) as max, 
    avg(len(password)) as avg 
FROM website.yourSchema.Password
```

The structure when calling will be:

```
yourDataBase.yourSchemaName.yourTableName
```